# Can I get the graph from the Neo4j database and populate it onto my asp.net application using visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, neo4j

I want to populate the result of a query (graph) onto my webpage. Is it possible?

I have written the following code to connect with Neo4j to my application:

```
public HelloWorldExample(string uri, string user, string password)
{
    _driver = GraphDatabase.Driver(uri, AuthTokens.Basic(user, password));
}

public string PrintGreeting(string message)
{
    using (var session = _driver.Session())
    {
        var greeting = session.WriteTransaction(tx =>
        {
            int id = 6566951;
            //var result = tx.Run("CREATE (a:Greeting) " +
            //                    "SET a.message = $message " +
            //                    "RETURN  a.message + ', from node ' + id(a)",
            //    new { message });
            var result = tx.Run("MATCH (c:Customer {customerID:" + id + "})<-[:IS_AFFILIATED_FROM]-(d:Customer) RETURN c,d");


            return result.As<string>();
            //Single()[0].
        });
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

the lines in the comment are to print message hello world. the part after that is a query to access graph in my database. Is it possible to access that graph by any means in my application as a visualization effect?